# how to make the ruby on rails with mysql environment in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

how to make the ruby on  rails with mysql environment in ubuntu 11.04.

I use the

```
sudo apt-get install ruby

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then I try

```
gem install rails
```

But I do not know to to install the mysql adapter?

Is there a document which I can follow?

---

**Update:**

Now,I install the gems use

```
gem install rails.
```

There are no errors.

However when I run

```
rails -v
```

I got 'rails' is not installed,you can typing sudo apt-get install rails

However when I change to the rails bin directory,and use the ruby to run the rails script,I can get the version:

```
xx@mac:/$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
xx@mac:/$ cd /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/
xx@mac:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin$ ruby rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
xx@mac:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin$
```

So,it seems that this is caused that the 'rails' can not be run directly,how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use RVM to manage your Rubies and Gems instead of the distro's Ruby.

See RVM documentation : http://www.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/

As soon as you have RVM and a Ruby interpreter installed, install the rails gem (with MRI 1.9.2 and a gemset called "your_gemset") :

```
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset use your_gemset
gem install rails
```

Generate your Rails project, then update the Gemfile (in your project directory) : remove the sqlite3 adapter entry and replace it with the mysql2 adapter :

```
# Gemfile
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
```

Finally, edit your database.yml file with [your MySQL configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include dependencies:

```
gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

The following link is a good resource.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm

Comment: I use `gem install rails`,and it install many gems,but when I try `rails -v` it show me that `The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:sudo apt-get install rails`